# Get bind atribute list in model asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection

I have a controller in like this with my custom filter

```
    [GetBindValueFilter]
    public ActionResult EditArtist([Bind(Include = "ID,ArtistName,ArtistDescription,CoverLink")]Artist modelArtist)
    {


        return View(modelArtist);
    }
```

and my custom filter to get bind value  is

```
 public class GetBindValueFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private string keysString;
    public GetBindValueFilterAttribute(string keys)
        : base()
    {
        this.keysString = keys;
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext);
    {

        //I want to get result like this
        var bindPropertyList="ID,ArtistName,ArtistDescription,CoverLink"

        // I try this code but it don't work
        //var modelList = filterContext.ActionParameters.ToList();
        //foreach (var model in modelList)
        //{
        //    var bAttri = model.Value.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof (BindAttribute), false);
        //      
        //}
        //
    }
}
```

Help me to solve this. I want to get result like this

> ```
>       var bindPropertyList="ID,ArtistName,ArtistDescription,CoverLink"
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the input parameters of the controller action using `filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters()`. Then you can query the attributes of each parameter in the same way as you were doing (using `GetCustomAttributes`).

For example, this action filter will correctly extract the include list of the modelArtist parameter:

```
public class GetBindValueFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string KeysString { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        foreach (var inputParameter in filterContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters())
        {
            var bindAttribute = inputParameter.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BindAttribute), false)
                                              .Cast<BindAttribute>()
                                              .FirstOrDefault();
            if (bindAttribute != null) this.KeysString += " " + bindAttribute.Include;
        }

    }
}
```

As a side note, you may want to reconsider your `GetBindValueFilterAttribute` to support controller actions with multiple parameters. In that case probably instead of extracting a string you would extract a dictionary (parameterName-keysStrings). In any case the code above should be enough for you to continue.

Hope that helps!